# Android app crashes after activity starts

Tags: android, multithreading, geolocation, proximitysensor

I have my app detecting when a person moves and when the move checking if it is in a certain proximity, or that is at least what I think it is doing. It starts the activity but then soon crashes and I have no logcat output as my device is not recognised on Eclipse. I'm not sure if I should have this code multithreaded and that this is the problem. It will send a text when the proximity is reached but this code has not been added yet.

```
package com.example.drivetext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class targetdistance extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.target);

    LocationManager locationManager;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    int t = 5000; //milliseconds
    int distance = 5; //meters
    LocationListener myLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        //Update application based on new location.
            setProximityAlert();
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
            //Update application if provider disabled.
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
            //Update application if provider enabled.
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras){
            //Update application if provider hardware status changed.
        }
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,t,distance,myLocationListener);
}
    final String TREASURE_PROXIMITY_ALERT = "com.paad.treasurealert";

    private void setProximityAlert() {

        LocationManager locationManager;
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        double coord1 = intent.getParcelableExtra("Coordinate1");
        double coord2 = intent.getParcelableExtra("Coordinate2");
        float seldis = 0;
        seldis = intent.getFloatExtra("SelectedDistance", seldis);

        double lat = coord1;
        double lng = coord2;
        float radius = seldis; //meters
        long expiration = -1; //do not expire

        Intent proxIntent = new Intent(TREASURE_PROXIMITY_ALERT);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, -1, proxIntent, 0);
        locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat,lng,radius,expiration,proximityIntent);

    }

}
```

Here is my logcat from the crash:

```
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946): Process: com.example.drivetext, PID: 18946
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at  com.example.drivetext.targetdistance.setProximityAlert(targetdistance.java:49)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at com.example.drivetext.targetdistance.access$0(targetdistance.java:44)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at com.example.drivetext.targetdistance$1.onLocationChanged(targetdistance.java:28)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:279)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:208)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:224)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
05-13 02:13:25.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 02:13:27.121: I/Process(18946): Sending signal. PID: 18946 SIG: 9
05-13 02:13:27.501: D/skia(19753): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:48 height:48 bitmap id is 270 
05-13 02:13:27.521: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(19753): Parent view is not a TextView
```

This is my setdistance class, This is the activity active before the targetdistance class.

```
package com.example.drivetext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class setdestination extends Activity implements OnMapLongClickListener {

        private GoogleMap map;          
        Location myLocation;
        TextView tvLocInfo;
        double pointfinallat;
        double pointfinallng;
        ListView listview;
        ArrayList<String> distancesendList;
        String finaldistance;
        String contactNo;
        String message;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.setdestination);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            contactNo = intent.getStringExtra("PhoneNumber");
            message = intent.getStringExtra("TextMessage");
            Toast.makeText(this, contactNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                

            ListView distanceList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


            distancesendList = new ArrayList<String>();
            getdistances();
            // Create The Adapter with passing ArrayList as 3rd parameter
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, distancesendList);
            // Set The Adapter
            distanceList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

            // register onClickListener to handle click events on each item
            distanceList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
               {
                        // argument position gives the index of item which is clicked
                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3)
                       {                             
                               String selecteddistance=distancesendList.get(position);
                               finaldistance = selecteddistance;
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Distance Selected : "+selecteddistance,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
               });

            tvLocInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

            FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            map = myMapFragment.getMap();

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

            Button chooseDistance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnchooseDistance);
              chooseDistance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {              
                 public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     if (finaldistance != null)
                     {
                         Intent intent3 = new Intent(setdestination.this, targetdistance.class);
                         intent3.putExtra("PhoneNumber", contactNo);
                         intent3.putExtra("TextMessage", message);
                         intent3.putExtra("Coordinate1", pointfinallat);
                         intent3.putExtra("Coordinate2", pointfinallng);
                         intent3.putExtra("SelectedDistance", finaldistance);
                         startActivity(intent3);
                     }
                     }
              });
        }

        void getdistances()
        {
            distancesendList.add("100");
            distancesendList.add("250");
            distancesendList.add("500");
            distancesendList.add("1000");
        }

        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));

            pointfinallat = point.latitude;
            pointfinallng = point.longitude;

            Toast.makeText(this, point.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   }
```

Comment: I have no logcat as the S5 is not recognised by Eclipse so I upload the file via google drive.

Comment: You could use an logcat app from the play store. Have you declared the required permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes all permissions are declared. Will try the app and post its results.

Comment: Any app in particular that would do the job? Can't seem to find one that works.

Comment: Trying not to advertise anything, if you have root you can use for example catlog or aLogcat. You also could try to use the adb.exe in the android sdk in the subfolder `platform-tools`. Call it with `adb logcat` from the command line while your device is connected via usb in development mode.

Comment: Which is line 49 in your file?

Comment: double coord1 = intent.getParcelableExtra("Coordinate1");

Comment: I'm guessing the intent is null

Comment: Meaning that the intent doesn't do anything when it is fired?

Comment: Please try to put the `getIntent()` call directly in the `onCreate()` method, get the coordinates via `getDoubleExtra` and save them to fields like in the setdestination class

Comment: Spot on luxer, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to add the doubles values to the intent but rather use the Bundle and attach it to the intent.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putDouble("Coordinate1", pointfinallat);
b.putDouble("Coordinate2", pointfinallng);
intent3.putExtras(b);
```

and if you are getting the bundle from activity intent

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

double coord1 = b.getDouble("Coordinate1");
double coord2 = b.getDouble("Coordinate2");
```